# PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed hd_ipc_send: not connected

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I have just installed the latest version of `SDK` and `ADT` .when i open the logcat i found that the whole logcat was filled with the following message.still i am not start any project on eclipse!

```
PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
hd_ipc_send: not connected
```

I just 10 minutes the number of this kind of messages reached more than 10,000 and i am fed up with this. Please tell me how can i remove this message from appearing in the logcat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was getting this error and discovered that it was a problem with `Bluestacks`. `Bluestacks` is an `Android emulator` for the PC that I had recently installed. Once I quit `Bluestacks` (which always runs in the background) the problem stopped.

**Update:**
 If you really need bluestacks you can filter this messages by creating logcat filter or just go "System tray (which display in lower-right corner, in windows) then right click on blustack icon and click on "quit" then your problem will solve.

Comment: I accessed the task manager as administrator and finished the Process "hd-block", +1 for you, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/ISQTL0YxUuY) . Looks like its an official bug related to the emulator system image.

Comment: Thanks for your link..  When I removed BlueStack the problem immediately disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

i have also same problem but i knew that it create by blustack , so please go "hidden icons" (which display in lower-right corner) then right click on blustack icon and click on "quit" then your problem will solve , try it...

if any problem then ask me...

Answer (score 0):

Bluestacks needs to be closed(COMPLETELY) for this error to disappear. Just to add to bala's answer, it is important to end all bluestacks processes. For this, **see the processes from all the users** in the task manager(assuming you're on Windows) & kill each bluestack process.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Bluestack. In my case, just stopping the program (quit option) was not enought.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was definitely Bluestacks.. Though I do suggest you to close Eclipse if you're considering to uninstall! The LogCat does not adapt quickly to environment changes and you might get the message even after you uninstall.